# Wrap ffmpeg for extracting audio from video in a python function

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, python

I'd like to wrap ffmpeg in a python function for extracting audio from video. I can successfully extract audio from mp4 videos on the command line.

```
ffmpeg -i sourcevideo.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audiotrack.m4a
```

But the below function throws a weird error and I cannot find a solution:

```
def extractAudioTrack(self,inputFilename):
    print "extract audio from of: " + inputFilename
    command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
                '-i', inputFilename,
                '-vn', 
                '-acodec', 'copy', 
                '-f', 'm4a',
                '-'
                ]
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE)
    return StringIO(pipe.proc.stdout.read())
```

Error:

```
[NULL @ 0x657480] Requested output format 'm4a' is not a suitable output format
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're sample command line does not match your code.  Your sample command doesn't have `-f m4a`, maybe remove that from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. MP4 cannot write to a pipe and thus it cannot stream. To be abe to stream, it needs to be able to seek back at the beginning of the file to write the output header when it is finished.

I found a solution to fix this. Simply add the option -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov.